# Handling Inversify @inject() parameters at class instantiation using typescript

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, constructor, electron, inversifyjs

Trying to implement a DI using *Inversify*, it is not clear how I can achieve a class instantiation without any parameters, when having a dependency injection. This is nearly equivalent to angulars DI. In angular one is able to construct classes containing injections without any @Inject parameters.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Container } from 'inversify';

export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    let container = new Container(); // maybe use { autoBindInjectable: true }
    const instance = new DatabaseService(); // DatabaseService is injectable
  }
}
```

The root module creates an Inversify `Container` and which collects all injectable class instantiations. The `DatabaseService` class should contain all database operations and has an `@injectable` decorator.

**models.ts**

```js
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { inject } from 'inversify';

export class Models {
  constructor(@inject(DatabaseService) dbService: DatabaseService) {}
}
```

The `Models` gets the injectable instance of `DatabaseService`. In another class I now want to create an instance of `Models`. How can I achieve a class instatiation without any parameters? Like it is in angular.

**myclass.ts**

```js
import { Models } from './models.component'

export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    models = new Models() // Want no constructing parameters!
  }
}
```

Do you have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly are you using inversify? What does it do?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I want to have an angular like DI for my electron application. E.g. the DatabaseService should be injected into multiple classes, but I only want to handle a single instance of it in the complete application.

Comment: You can already do that. Just add the service to `providers` in `app.module.ts` and it will only have 1 instance.

Comment: Do you mean like in this [example](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/provider_injection.md)?

Comment: No. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that Inversify you can simply use what is already provided by Angular itself. Create a new module which will handle your app's instances:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    DatabaseService
  ]
})

export class CoreModule {

  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() private parentModule: CoreModule) {

    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error('CoreModule already loaded');
    }
  }
}
```

The check in the constructor there is optional but prevents `CoreModule` from being loaded twice, ensuring that your injectables only have 1 instance.

Then import this module into `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Now you can drop Inversify altogether.

Comment: Yeah I know how to use angular DI, but I want to avoid it, as it is completely overkill. I only need DI in angulars way. If there is no way, I will try your solution.

Comment: I don't understand how this is overkill. Are you not using Angular? Because right now you're including an entire library for something that is already provided by Angular. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No I'm not using angular for my electron "backend" project. I'm using angular to create my frontends and use its output in my electron apps. Also I'm not familiar in using angular without angular CLI and without any html template output, and just transpile the typescript. If that's possible it would be awesome.

Comment: Ok, then I don't really know since I've never used Electron. Perhaps it would be best to remove the angular tag from the question as it's quite confusing. I thought you were trying to create a singleton service in an angular environment, not electron.

Comment: Used the angular tag, because I want to achieve an angular like DI.